# File ownership changes on save for "some" files

Tags: server, permissions, samba, groups

On my server, I have two accounts; one for me and one for my wife. We both share the same group as our primary group.

For simple text files, when I own the file and she edits and saves that file, ownership and group do not change. They stay as me the owner. Same thing happens when she owns a file and I edit and then save it.

But when either one of us owns a Photoshop file (.PSD) and the other one edits it, the ownership changes to the person who last saved the file. I could see ownership changing if I was doing a "Save As", but I'm not; just hitting the save.

We're both using own own desktops and getting our files off the server through Samba.

Anyone have any thoughts as to what might be causing this particular behavior? Maybe it's normal for all I know, but if it was it seems like it would do the same to simple text files.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the file is actually being deleted and recreated. I doubt photoshop is doing any kind of chmod'ing in the background.

Comment: I tried this with a .odt file in LibreOffice, and the ownership remained the same, as I would expect. I'm beginning to think this might be an idiosyncrasy of Photoshop. Imagine that! Anyway, the proper place for this discussion is probably on a Photoshop forum.